# Font.createTrueTypeFont not working

Tags: codenameone

```
Font f = Font.createTrueTypeFont("Airstrike 3D Regular", "airstrike3d.ttf").derive(50, Font.STYLE_BOLD);
img.getGraphics().setFont(f);
```

This is the code for adding ttf font. I copied .ttf file in src directory. When I am drawing text on image, its all the same. I tried with different font as well.

This is the code for drawing the text on image.

```
img.getGraphics().drawString("Inlet", 250, 100, getUnselectedStyle().TEXT_DECORATION_NONE);
```

I am not able to increase font size. Suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

```
Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
g.setFont(...);
g.drawString....
```

Comment: Good to hear. FYI assuming the answer is the correct answer you should accept it.